# Entity Framework Core : retrieving string with escaped backslash

Tags: c#, regex, entity-framework-core

We are storing regex patterns in a column, but when retrieving the string, regex patterns with double backslashes are escaped with additional double backslashes.

EDIT:
Fixed, pattern was already escaped in the database, which caused the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `Regex.Unescape(input)`?

Comment: Probably you are looking at them in debugger, which automatically escapes backslashes for visualization.

Comment: Actually, the pattern was already escaped in the database, which caused the problem.